# actionscript 3 tween bug

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

In first example tween(s) occasionally prematurely stop:

```
package {

    //are main stage is a movieclip
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*; 
    import fl.transitions.easing.None;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

    public class Game extends MovieClip {

        //varibles 
        public var brickStack1:Array = new Array(1);
        public var brickStack2:Array = new Array(1,1);
        public var brickStack3:Array = new Array(1,1,1);
        public var brickStack4:Array = new Array(1,1,1,1);
        public var brickStack5:Array = new Array(1,1,1,1,1);
        public var arrayOfBricks:Array = new Array(brickStack1,brickStack2,brickStack3,brickStack4,brickStack5);
        public var brickLoader:Timer = new Timer(2000,0);
        //public var arrayLength:int = 0;
        public var brickStack:int = 0;
        public var brickStackBottom:int = 0;
        var arrayLength:int = 0;
        var arrayLengthBottom:int = 0;
        var brickTween:Tween;

        public function Game() {

            trace("game");
            //addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER , loop);
            brickLoader.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER , loop);
            brickLoader.start();
            //create a new instance of the Brick

            //var brickTween = new Tween( k,"x", None.easeNone , k.x,k.x - 1000, 5, true);
        }




        function loop(e:TimerEvent):void {

            //declare a varible for the for loop with Math.random
            brickStack = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) ;
            //trace(brickStack);

            if(brickStack == 0) {

                brickStackBottom = 4;

            }
            if(brickStack == 1) {

                brickStackBottom = 3;

            }
            if(brickStack == 2) {

                brickStackBottom = 2;

            }
            if(brickStack == 3) {

                brickStackBottom = 1;

            }
            if(brickStack == 4) {

                brickStackBottom = 0;

            }

            arrayLength = arrayOfBricks[brickStack].length;
            arrayLengthBottom = arrayOfBricks[brickStackBottom].length;

            trace(arrayLengthBottom);
            //arrayOfBricks[brickStack];

            //brick load ratio 1:5       2:4      3:3      4:2      5:1 
                              //+4*5/5   +2*4/4   +0*3/3   -2*2/2   -4*1/1
            //formulate a mathmatically loader paradiam 


                for(var i:int = 0;i < arrayLength; i++){
                bottomLoop();


                var obj:Brick = new Brick();
                    obj.x = stage.stageWidth + obj.width;
                    obj.y = (i*40);
                    addChild(obj);


                brickTween = new Tween( obj,"x", None.easeNone , obj.x,obj.x - (stage.stageWidth + obj.width*3), 4, true);




                }


        }

        function bottomLoop() {
            for(var o:int = 0;o < arrayLengthBottom; o++){

            var objBottom:Brick = new Brick();
                    objBottom.x = stage.stageWidth + objBottom.width;
                    objBottom.y = (stage.stageHeight - 40) - (o*40);
                    addChild(objBottom);

                     brickTween = new Tween( objBottom,"x", None.easeNone , objBottom.x,objBottom.x - (stage.stageWidth + objBottom.width*3), 4, true);

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

In this example tween(s) prematurely but than moments later continue.

```
package {

    //are main stage is a movieclip
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*; 
    import fl.transitions.easing.None;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

    public class Game extends MovieClip {

        //varibles 
        public var brickStack1:Array = new Array(1);
        public var brickStack2:Array = new Array(1,1);
        public var brickStack3:Array = new Array(1,1,1);
        public var brickStack4:Array = new Array(1,1,1,1);
        public var brickStack5:Array = new Array(1,1,1,1,1);
        public var arrayOfBricks:Array = new Array(brickStack1,brickStack2,brickStack3,brickStack4,brickStack5);
        public var brickLoader:Timer = new Timer(2000,0);
        //public var arrayLength:int = 0;
        public var brickStack:int = 0;
        public var brickStackBottom:int = 0;
        var arrayLength:int = 0;
        var arrayLengthBottom:int = 0;
        var arrayOfObjects:Array = new Array();
        var i:int = 0;
        public function Game() {

            trace("game");
            //addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER , loop);
            brickLoader.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER , loop);
            brickLoader.start();
            //create a new instance of the Brick

            //var brickTween = new Tween( k,"x", None.easeNone , k.x,k.x - 1000, 5, true);
        }

        var brickTween:Tween;


        function loop(e:TimerEvent):void {

            //declare a varible for the for loop with Math.random
            brickStack = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) ;
            //trace(brickStack);

            if(brickStack == 0) {

                brickStackBottom = 4;

            }
            if(brickStack == 1) {

                brickStackBottom = 3;

            }
            if(brickStack == 2) {

                brickStackBottom = 2;

            }
            if(brickStack == 3) {

                brickStackBottom = 1;

            }
            if(brickStack == 4) {

                brickStackBottom = 0;

            }

            arrayLength = arrayOfBricks[brickStack].length;
            arrayLengthBottom = arrayOfBricks[brickStackBottom].length;

            trace(arrayLengthBottom);
            //arrayOfBricks[brickStack];

            //brick load ratio 1:5       2:4      3:3      4:2      5:1 
                              //+4*5/5   +2*4/4   +0*3/3   -2*2/2   -4*1/1
            //formulate a mathmatically loader paradiam 


                for(i = 0;i < arrayLength; i++){
                bottomLoop();


                var obj:Brick = new Brick();
                    obj.x = stage.stageWidth + obj.width;
                    obj.y = (i*40);

                    addChild(obj);
                    arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
                }
    tween();

        }

        function tween() {
            for(i=0;i <arrayOfObjects.length;i++){
            brickTween = new Tween( arrayOfObjects[i],"x", None.easeNone , arrayOfObjects[i].x,arrayOfObjects[i].x - (stage.stageWidth + 240), 6, true);
          }
        }
        function bottomLoop() {
            for(var o:int = 0;o < arrayLengthBottom; o++){

            var objBottom:Brick = new Brick();
                    objBottom.x = stage.stageWidth + objBottom.width;
                    objBottom.y = (stage.stageHeight - 40) - (o*40);
                    arrayOfObjects.push(objBottom)
                    addChild(objBottom);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweens usually prematurly stops when they are garbage collected.

for example:

```
var tweenObject:Tween;
brickTween = new Tween( firstTweenParams ); // first tween added
brickTween = new Tween( secondTweenParams ); /* second tween added 
and first MARKED for garbage collection (removal)*/
```

When marked for garbage collection, tween will work some time untill collected (destroyed). it may occur before tween finishes his work

There are 2 solutions:

1) You should store array of all your working tweens to avoid your issue. And clean worked out elements from array afterwards.

2) use tween library like:

GTween http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

or

tweenmax http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/